# Code to compute random number generates 1 only

Tags: java

The code supposed to compute a random number and you have to guess it to make the right answer but when I try to test it, the answer is always 1, why is that. 
here is the code

```
public class GuessGame
{
private int target;
private int max;
private int maxGuesses;
/**
    Constructs a new game by randomly selecting a target number
    between 1 and max_value.  Also assigns the maximum number of
    guesses by calling the calcGuesses method.
    @param max_value the largest possible target number
*/
public  GuessGame(int maxValue)
{
//this.max = maxValue* (int)Math.random() + 1;
this.target = (maxValue * (int)Math.random()) + 1;

}
/**
Checks if the provided guess is in the range between 1 and max_value.
@param guess the guess to check
@return returns true if the guess is in the appropriate range
*/
public boolean isValidGuess(int guess)
{
//implementation not shown  
if( guess >= 1 && guess <= max)
{
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
 }
/**
Checks if the provided guess matches the target number.
@param guess the guess to check
@return returns true if the guess matches the target, false otherwise
*/
public boolean isWinner(int guess)
 {
   //implementation not shown   
if( guess == target)
{
    return true;
   }
   else {
       return false;
      }
   }
  /**
Checks if the provided guess is too high or too low
Precondition: the guess is not equal to the target.
@param guess the guess to check
@return returns an appropriate message indicating too high or too low
   */
   public String determineHighLow(int guess)
  {
//implementation not shown  
if( guess > target)
{
    return "Too HIGH!";
   } 
   else if(guess < target)
   {
       return "Too LOW!";
   }
   return "The number you guessed is: " + guess;

  }
/**
Calculates the number of guesses to give the player based on the 
max_value selected.
    @return returns the number of guesses to give the player
*/
public int calcGuesses()

{
maxGuesses = 10 ; 
return maxGuesses;
   }

/**
Calculates the number of guesses remaining.
@param guesses the number of guesses the player has used so far
@return returns the number of guesses remaining
*/
  public int guessesLeft (int guesses)
{
//implementation not shown  
maxGuesses = maxGuesses - guesses;
return maxGuesses;
}
 }
```

and here is the tester class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GuessGameRunner
 {
/*
 * The GuessGameRunner class is the main class that works as follows.  
 * The main method prompts the user to enter a maximum value(re-prompting if the user enters a 
 * number less than 10 or any non-integer),
 * then constructs a new GuessGame object with that valid entered value.  
 * The following is then repeated until the player wins or runs out of guesses:
 * player is informed of number of guesses remaining and is prompted to make a guess 
 * (re-prompting if invalid); the guess is checked for winning—if not a winner, 
 * the player is told whether the guess is too high or low. 
 * After the repetition is complete, the appropriate winning or losing message is displayed. 
 * The winning message should include how many guesses the player took.
 */

   public static void main(String[] args)
{
 int target;
    Scanner goal = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess my number");
    target = goal.nextInt() ;




    GuessGame targetGuess = new GuessGame(10 );
   //targetGuess.GuessGame(target);
    target = targetGuess.calcGuesses();

   System.out.println(targetGuess.calcGuesses());
    int bool = goal.nextInt();



    while(targetGuess.isWinner(bool)== false && target > 0)
    {
    System.out.println( targetGuess.isValidGuess(bool));

    System.out.println(targetGuess.isWinner(bool));
    if (target != bool)
    {
        System.out.println("guesses left: " +    targetGuess.guessesLeft(1));
        System.out.println(targetGuess.determineHighLow(bool));
   }
   bool = goal.nextInt();
}
 System.out.println( targetGuess.isValidGuess(bool));
 System.out.println(targetGuess.determineHighLow(bool));

    System.out.println(targetGuess.isWinner(bool));
 }
}
```

again the math.random() when I multiply and add 1 it doesn't seem to be give me any random numbers the answer is always one, please help!

Comment: Please make a title which describes the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing this

```
(int) Math.random()
```

since Math.random() method returns a double between 0 and 1, you are
truncating  that double into a int resulting always to be **0**

try to modify the cast where the cast operation occurs and remember that integer operated against integer returns integers.

```
target = (int) (maxValue * Math.random()) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` returns a number between `0` and `1`. That means `(int)Math.random()` will **always** be `0`, which in turn lets `this.target = (maxValue * (int)Math.random()) + 1;` always evaluate to `1`. In order to fix this, simply do the cast outside of the calculation:

```
this.target = (int)(maxValue * Math.random() + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
this.target = (maxValue * (int)Math.random()) + 1;
```

From the Javadoc for Math.random():

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

So you get a value in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0[ and cast that to an int. Since casting to an int just rounds down, the result of `(int)Math.random()` is always going to be 0. Multiply that with maxValue, it's still 0. Plus one, and now `this.target` is always set to 1 as a result.

Check out class `Random` and use [method `nextInt(int n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) to get a random integer in interval [0, n[ (note that n is exclusive).